# Inserir marcação em progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Não consegui encontrar uma forma de inserir uma marcação na barra, estou tentando mostrar uma média.

Como é:

[image]

Como eu gostaria de mostrar a média:

[image]

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso com bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma sugestão de implementação com "Stacked", exemplo:

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmFzL/1/)**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 50%">
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 5%">
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 45%">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Resultado:**
[image: Progress bar]

Outra maneira seria criar uma classe e posicionar sobre o `progress-bar`, exemplo:

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmFzL/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 50%">
  </div>
  <span class="marcador"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.marcador{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:10%;
    width:5px; 
    height:80px; 
    background-color:red;
}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: progress span]

Comment: Cara, o foda é que neste exemplo que você deu eu perco a minha marcação principal saca? Mas essa sua sugestão me ajudou a pensar em uma nova possibilidade, vou tentar e qualquer coisa eu mando o resultado. De qualquer forma valeeu!

Comment: @AlessandroGomes, entendo, mais você pode também utilizar uma classe como marcador, posicionando sobre o progress, veja neste link http://jsfiddle.net/vmFzL/2/, se solucionar edito minha resposta adicionando a solução, mais sinceramente, sugiro utilizar a primeira opção e reajustar sua marcação

Comment: Caraaa essa segunda solução é melhor para a aplicação que eu preciso aqui! se quiser editar a resposta, manda ver. Valeeu

Comment: @AlessandroGomes editei a resposta com o método alternativo